# Prevent push upgrade from packaging org

Tags: managed-package, push-upgrade, packaging

Consider orgId: abc

Is there a way to block a push upgrade for 'abc' from the packaging org even if the org 'abc' is selected from the 'Schedule Push Upgrade' page?

I realise that not selecting the org 'abc' is always an option, but want to see if there is a programmatic way (trigger/flag) to prevent human errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  On the Package Detail page click Edit. At the bottom there is a text box labeled Push Upgrade Exclusion List.  Enter a comma delimited list of OrgIds and you won't be able to push to them.

The orgs that you exclude are still in the list to be selected for the Push Upgrade.  If you select them (as in when you do a select all) the excluded orgs will return a failed install message like so:

[image: Ineligible Upgrade]